# Adding title to navigation bar ReactNative using props

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-redux

I need to know how to set a title on my header. Here's my code:

I am trying to set a value to the title of my Navigation bar using props. Here's my approach. However, it doesn't work. Can someone help me sort this out.

**Index.Ios Class**

```
...
export default class pro extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <Container>
        <He sometext={'sd'}/>


      </Container>
    );
  }
}
...
```

**Header.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header,  Body,  Title } from 'native-base';

export default class He extends Component {
  render(props) {
    return (

        <Header>

          <Body>
            <Title>{props.sometext}</Title>
          </Body>

        </Header>

    );
  }
}

module.export = He;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your problem

For your problem, I think you're missing the `this.props.sometext`. The `render` method in React doesn't take argument ([doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)). Instead, you can access to the component props via `this.props`.

#### Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header,  Body,  Title } from 'native-base';

export default class He extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <Header>

          <Body>
            <Title>{this.props.sometext}</Title> // <==== HERE
          </Body>

        </Header>

    );
  }
}

module.export = He;
```

## Better navigation bar management

If you need more complex usage of your navigation bar like navigating between views and passing props, you can use [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) in order to do this.

You can start with the [Getting Started](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) page to setup everything right.

Comment: Well, I need to set the title from the `Getting Started page` , and retrieve+displaty the value in the `header.js` page. How can I sort this ? It's like passing a parameter from one class and getting it displayed in another.

Comment: Thanks it worked. +1 for `react-navigation`. I am a newbie. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Illep, you're welcome :) If you need guides, I recommend the [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html), there are a lot of beginner guides about many topics (like navigation, list, etc.). Happy coding!